# Can I avoid using the whole entities for data on related tables with TypeOrm?

Tags: typeorm

I have those sample entities with a N:N relation on TypeOrm:

```
export default class Model extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToMany(type => Market, market => market.id,{ onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
  @JoinTable({ 'name': 'model_enabled_markets' })
  marketsEnabled: Market[];
  //...
}
export default class Market extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToMany<Model>(type => Model, model => model.id,{ onDelete: 'RESTRICT'})
  enabledModels: Promise<Model[]>;
  //...
}
```

When about to save a new Model instance to the database, if I have the ids I need to place on the `marketsEnabled`, is there any way I can use them directly? Or do I need to query the required Markets with those IDs, and assign an array with them?

Comment: The second argument of `@ManyToMany` decorater expects the inverse navigation property of the relation, not the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeORM expects that all entity objects (will) exist in a relation array (this is necessary, for example, because of the [cascade option](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#cascades)). Besides that, typescript also expects an object that matches that of the model, so it is probably not enough to just pass an object with an `id` field only.

To manipulate the join table directly, it is best to [create it yourself](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md#many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties) as an entity class. This allows you to add or remove individual foreign id rows without first loading all relation entries in the navigation properties (relation arrays) of linked entity objects.